# When fitting an arima model, how do I pick the residuals?

Tags: time-series, residuals

Let's say I have a time series $x_1, ..., x_t$. I fit an AR model and get my estimated parameters.

Then I can simulate from this, but in order to do so, I also need some distribution from which I draw residuals.

If I want my simulation to fit my time series as good as possible, how do I do that? What residuals do I use (or how to estimate such residuals).

Comment: If you are using `R`, `residuals(object)`  will give you the exact residuals from  your data and fitted model. If you are simulating and want the residuals to be as close to theoretical as possible, you can generate normal data with mean 0 and variance 1.

Comment: better yet as AUTOBOX does it actually takes the model residuals and uses that distribution of values to launch a monte carlo simualtion for the future optionally enabling the incorporation of future spikes/pulses into the uncertainty/ . it is a very dangerous practice to assume that the residuals are normal they are what they are !